# VB.NET Stop a timer in its timer tick

Tags: vb.net, timer

How do I stop a timer in its own timer tick? This is the code so far:

```
Private Sub replyTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles replyTimer.Tick
    MsgBox("Hello!")
    Me.replyTimer.Stop()
End Sub
```

But for some reason, it doesn't stop.

Comment: What is the interval on the timer?  If it is too short it might be firing multiple times before you have a chance to stop it.

Comment: You are going to have to click the OK button of that message box quicker.  Or just put the Stop() call *before* you call MsgBox().

Answer (score 2):

First of all:

The enabled property for the timer must be "False", so the timer doesn't start when form loaded.

and you have to make sure that: in the other parts of your code there is no command or loop to restart the timer.

and to stop the timer... you just need this code :

```
Private Sub replyTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles replyTimer.Tick
     replyTimer.Stop()    
     MsgBox("Hello!")
End Sub
```

so every time the timer starts : the message will pop, and the timer will not restart.

To start the timer again write:

```
replytimer.start()
```

i hope my answer was useful to you :)

Comment: The sender should be the replytimer instance... it would probably be better to `DirectCast(sender, Timer).Stop()`